Преобразование пиксельных координат в угловые и на оборот
у меня есть некоторый набор настроек камеры - азимут,угол местности, ширина охвата по вертикали и горизонтали. и мне нужно по этим данным пиксельные координаты преобразовать в угловые и наоборот. Если кто-то сталкивался, посоветуйте, пожалуйста алгоритм, ссылки и тд для решения данного вопроса. Спасибо
